# Form in iframe - dropdown always losing focus to input element (Chrome only)

Tags: html, iframe, focus

I have a simple form in an iframe.
For demo purposes it only has a select and two text inputs.

After a fresh load I can open the dropdown.
As soon as I have clicked in an input field and that input field got the focus I cannot use the dropdown anymore.
It always immediately loses its focus to the last text input I have used.

You can see a demo here:
https://iframe.testlive.net/

This seems to be a Chrome issue (latest Chrome version on Windows 11).
There is no problem with Firefox and interestingly also no issue with Edge.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks as if this issue is caused by a Chrome plugin: Enpass Password Manager.
I will file a bug report with Enpass.